# Область работы JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, opencart, область-видимости

Добрый день уважаемые.

Довольно часто при работе над чужими проектами (обычно на `CMS OpenCart`) сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что код, который прописанный не прямо вот под реагирующим на него элементов не хочет отрабатывать. С чем это может быть связано?

Приведу пример, есть 3 `.tpl` файла - `header.tpl`, `main.tpl`, `footer.tpl` и файл со скриптами `common.js`

Бывает такое что мой скрипт, который я кладу в `common.js` не срабатывает. Зато если я его инлайново пропишу в `header.tpl` (допустим некий скрипт для навигации по сайту), то он срабатывает.

С чем это может быть связано? В обоих случаях прописываю обработку скрипта только после полной загрузки страницы

```
$(document).ready(function () { ...})
```

Comment: консолька что-нибудь показывает, ошибки связаные с undefined?

Comment: Кэш обновляли? (CRTL+F5)

Comment: Это случаем не SPA? или его убогая имитация? когда сначала грузяться скрипты, а потом уже происходит наполнение элементами? Попробуйте просто выборк для начала, getElementBy

Comment: В консоле ошибок не наблюдается, Кэш обновлял и сбрасывал, не помогло. Про SPA не слышал, но не понятна сама идея, я ведь прописываю свой скрипт в функуии ready что по сути должно его запускать только после полной загрузки страници какая ему разница в header я его держу или после footer ?